# Adding to text file without deleting

Tags: c#, text, streamwriter

I need to add 4 variable numbers into a single line but using the current code it just replaces the numbers thus making it pointless.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("build.txt"))
{
    writer.Write(" " + layer + " " + x + " " + y + " " + block);
    Console.WriteLine("[" + layer + "," + x + "," + y + "," + block + "]");                   
}
```

so I needed it to write...

```
 l x y b l x y b l x y b l x y b ...
```

...but it did not work out like that, and the internet wasn't particularly helpful, hopefully here can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx), personally... That way you can just specify the text you want to write, and the method will open the file, append the text, and then close the file.

If you really want to use the writer though, you could use [`File.AppendText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx):

```
using (var writer = File.AppendText("build.txt"))
{
    writer.Write(...);
}
```

Or you can use the [`StreamWriter` constructor with an `append` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx). I'd definitely recommend using the methods in `File` though - they're much clearer to read.

Comment: Yes, use Jon's example. :)

Comment: Thanks, but it writes it out on a new line each, whereas I want it to be written on row 1.

Comment: @BananaVenom: It won't if you use just `writer.Write`. It doesn't add a new line automatically. Did you use `WriteLine` instead?

Answer (score 5):

StreamWriter [has a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) that accepts a boolean value to indicate that you want to append to the current text and not overwrite it

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("build.txt", true))
{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) for this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("build.txt")) 
{
   sw.Write(" " + layer + " " + x + " " + y + " " + block);
   Console.WriteLine("[" + layer + "," + x + "," + y + "," + block + "]");
}
```