# Line erased when i write a new line to a .txt file - Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I'm just a code enthusiast.
This code is from a chronometer I'm doing and I'm using this code on a button press event. The intent is to write on a .txt file the current time on the chronometer and the time the button was pressed.

```
 System.IO.StreamWriter filewrite = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\joaof\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\Resources\times.txt");

 filewrite.Write("\r\n" + label1.Text + "\r\nAt: " + System.DateTime.Now + "\r\n");
 filewrite.Close();
```

The problem is that whenever i click the button again to save a new time it erases the previous one and writes it.

[what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LShpG.png)

[whats supposed to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gITB9.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding to text file without deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366827/adding-to-text-file-without-deleting) or [How to write data to a text file in C# without overwriting the current data](//stackoverflow.com/q/5516870)

Comment: For info, `StreamWriter` is `IDisposable`, so should be in a `using` block as shown in the answer below and one of the duplicate questions. By doing this the implicit `Dispose` (done when it exits the using block) will take care of the `Close`, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
File.AppendText(filepath, text);
```

or

```
using (var filewrite = new StreamWriter(filepath, append: true))
{
    filewrite.Write(.....);
}
```

Comment: @JonhyOliveira The best way to thank the person is to upvote and/or accept an answer. IMHO this is the better of the two current answers, since it offers two solutions, and the StreamWriter option has added the improvement of a using block; but it's your question, so you get to pick. Press the 'tick' next to the one you want to accept.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in append mode, try the following:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter filewrite = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\joaof\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\Resources\times.txt", append: true);

filewrite.Write("\r\n" + label1.Text + "\r\nAt: " + System.DateTime.Now + "\r\n");
filewrite.Close();
```

Notice the `append: true`

Comment: If this post solved your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer. Glad I could help 